# How can I add a dropdownlist title before populating it with database results in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am aware that the title attribute does not exist for select menus in HTML, so usually I just have an option with an empty value at the top that says "Select Item" and then I have it selected by default.  My problem is that the select menu in my ASP project is bound to data fields.  The extra option I am adding from my C# file is not appearing.  I assume it is because the data fields are overwriting this extra option.  I have also tried adding a ListItem inside the dropdownlist in my aspx file.  This does nothing.  How can I add this extra option?

Here's my C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring;
            connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetCourses", conn);

            conn.Open();
            DDCourses.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Course", "0"));
            DDCourses.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DDCourses.DataTextField = "courseName";
            DDCourses.DataValueField = "courseId";
            DDCourses.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Here's the ASP:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDCourses" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDCourses_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            SelectCommand="GetCourses" DataTextField="courseName" DataValueField="courseId">
     <asp:ListItem selected="True" Text="Select Course"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert it programmatically, but do so **after** the databind.

```
DDCourses.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Course", "0"));
DDCourses.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Ahh ok.  I was under the assumption that since I wanted it to appear at the beginning of the list, I had to add that code before I bound the data to the dropdown list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the property:

```
AppendDataBoundItems="true"
```

Also make sure in your Page_Load() has:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // databind code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your problem is that, You are adding an additional item before assigning the datasource. So that At the time of assigning the datasource the DropDownList is loaded with the new datasource. So what you have to do is that Insert item to the `0th` index after assigning the datasource. The snippet will be like the following:

```
 DDCourses.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 DDCourses.DataTextField = "courseName";
 DDCourses.DataValueField = "courseId";
 DDCourses.DataBind();
 DDCourses.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Course", "0"));
```

And if you want the inserted item to be selected by default you need to write a single line `DDCourses.SelectedIndex = 0;` after the insert statement